# jQuery - Wrapping a list of image tags with anchor tags

Tags: jquery

I need to make this:

```
<div class="image-dump">
<img src="dir/file1.jpg"/>
<img src="dir/file2.jpg"/>
<img src="dir/file3.jpg"/>
<img src="dir/file4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Render like so:

```
<div class="image-dump">
<a href="dir/file1.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="dir/file2.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file2.jpg"/></a>
<a href="dir/file3.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file3.jpg"/></a>
<a href="dir/file4.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file4.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

**Note:**
The href's value needs to be pulled from the img's src value,

Please help!!

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.image-dump > img').wrapAll(function() {
    return $('<a />', { 'href': this.src, 'rel': 'group', 'class': 'overlay' });   
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/us9vB/).

#### Input

```
<div class="image-dump">
    <img src="dir/file1.jpg"/>
    <img src="dir/file2.jpg"/>
    <img src="dir/file3.jpg"/>
    <img src="dir/file4.jpg"/>
</div>
```

#### Output

```
<div class="image-dump">
<a href="dir/file1.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file1.jpg"></a>
<a href="dir/file2.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file2.jpg"></a>
<a href="dir/file3.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file3.jpg"></a>
<a href="dir/file4.jpg" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="dir/file4.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div.image-dump img').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="' + this.src + '" rel="group" class="overlay"><img src="' + this.src + '" /></a>');
});
```

Comment: @Manbearpig I like to _hope_ that you also understand why it works rather than just copying/pasting in the answer. Doing that will get you no where in developing.

Comment: Nice, only issue is you will [lose events](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/us9vB/1/).

Comment: True, and in that respect one of the other solutions are probably better.  I should have posted this with wrap just to prevent some newbie from getting confused as to why events stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".image-dump img").each(function(){
 var anch = $("a")
 anch.attr("href", $(this).attr("src"));
 anch.attr("rel", "group");
 $(this).wrap(anch);
});
```